# solve this equation in Z

Tags: linear-algebra, divisibility

Solve the equation over $\textbf{Z}$ :

$x^3$ - 3$y$ = 2

The only way I solve this problem was using the Fermat Theorem. Is there any chance to solve it without using the theorem? And the proof to be explained for the primary/secondary school children?

Comment: $x^3\equiv2\pmod3$?

Comment: So you say the theorem is for little children, but then you say that's the only way you can solve it?  I'm not sure what to make of that.

Comment: Nope. I say if there is any chance to solve it without the Fermat theory. Sorry for the misunderstandings.

Comment: There's always guess and check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know any theorems about primary school children. Take any integer $x = 3k-1$ for any integer $k,$ then $x^3 = 27k^3 - 27 k^2 + 9 - 1.$ So $x^3 - 2 = 27k^3 - 27 k^2 + 9 - 3.$ And
$$  \frac{x^3 - 2}{3} =  9k^3 - 9 k^2 + 3 - 1.$$ So, take
$$  x=3k-1, \; \; \; y =  9k^3 - 9 k^2 + 3 - 1. $$

Comment: Thanks for your response! Btw, could we choose $x=3k+2$ also?

Comment: @MFGFlay, $3(k+1)- 1 = 3k+2.$ As $k$ can be any integer, positive, negative, zero, as desired, you do not gain anything new that way. Or, put another way, i don't know what you are talking about.